# What is a good platform for building a game framework targeting both web and native languages?

Tags: javascript, c++, flash, opengl, lisp

I would like to develop (or find, if one is already in development) a framework with support for accelerated graphics and sound built on a system flexible enough to compile to the following:

- native ppc/x86/x86_64/arm binaries or a language which compiles to them
- JavaScript
- ActionScript bytecode or a language which compiles to it (ActionScript 3, Haxe)
- optionally Java

I imagine, for example, creating an API where I can open windows and make OpenGL-like calls and the framework maps this in a relatively efficient manner to either WebGL with a canvas object, 3d graphics in Flash, OpenGL ES 2 with EGL, or desktop OpenGL in an X11, Windows, or Cocoa window.

I have so far looked into these avenues:

- Building the game library in [Haxe](http://haxe.org/)

  - Pros:

    - Targets exist for PHP, JavaScript, ActionScript bytecode, C++
    - High level, object oriented language
  - Cons:

    - No support for finally{} blocks or destructors, making resource cleanup difficult
    - C++ target does not allow room for producing highly optimized libraries -- the foreign function interface requires all primitive types be boxed in a wrapper object, as if writing bindings for a scripting language; these feel unideal for real-time graphics and audio, especially exporting low-level functions.
    - Doesn't seem quite yet mature
- Using the C preprocessor to create a translator, writing programs entirely with macros

  - Pros:

    - CPP is widespread and simple to use
  - Cons:

    - This is an arduous task and probably the wrong tool for the job
    - CPP implementations differ widely in support for features (e.g. xcode cpp has no variadic macros despite claiming C99 compliance)
    - There is little-to-no room for optimization in this route
- Using [llvm](http://llvm.org/)'s support for multiple backends to target c/c++ to web languages

  - Pros:

    - Can code in c/c++
    - LLVM is a very mature highly optimizing compiler performing e.g. global inlining
    - Targets exist for actionscript (alchemy) and javascript (emscripten)
  - Cons:

    - Actionscript target is closed source, unmaintained, and buggy.
    - Javascript targets do not use features of HTML5 for appropriate optimization (e.g. linear memory with typed arrays) and are immature
    - An LLVM target must convert from low-level bytecode, so high-level constructs are lost and bloated unreadable code is created from translating individual instructions, which may be more difficult for an unprepared JIT to optimize.   "jump" instructions cause problems for languages with no "goto" statements.
- Using [libclang](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2010-11/Gregor-libclang.pdf) to write a translator from C/C++ to web languages

  - Pros:

    - A beautiful parsing library providing easy access to the code structure
    - Can code in C/C++
    - Has sponsored developer effort from Apple
  - Cons:

    - Incomplete; current feature set targets IDEs.  Basic operators are unexposed and must be manually parsed from the returned AST element to be identified.
    - Translating code prior to compilation may forgo optimizations assumed in c/c++ such as inlining.
- Creating new code generators for [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) to translate into web languages

  - Pros:

    - Can code in C/C++ as libclang
  - Cons:

    - There is no API; code structure is unstable
    - A much larger job than using libclang; the innards of clang are complex
- Building the game library in [Common Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp)

  - Pros:

    - Flexible, well-developed language
    - Extensive introspection should ease writing translators
    - Translators exist for at least javascript
  - Cons:

    - Unfamiliar language
    - No standardized library functions, widely varying implementations

Which of these avenues should I pursue?  Do you know of any others, or any systems that might be useful?

Does a general project like this exist somewhere already?

Thank you for any input.

Comment: I expect you won't find any meaningful solution.  These target platforms+languages are in some cases so different that there's not much point trying to target them simultaneously...

Comment: This question might be better suited to gamedev.se.

Comment: There are other approaches to tackle this problem. Writing whole game or game engine from single code base to all these platforms is next to impossible. But you can use scripts or go with C-preprocessor route to build actual game on top of "player engine" that takes care of the low-level stuff. Writing such an engine to all these platforms will be a huge task, but nevertheless interesting project. There are proprietary systems like that especially in mobile companies. 

Check out Unity 3D at least for some ideas. It seems to be a quite a hit for multiplatform game development nowadays.

Comment: Common Lisp is "ancient"?  Even C++ is older than it!

Comment: Good point.  But the C++ standard is still revised and developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a language currently in development by Blitz Research ( http://www.blitzbasic.com ), it is NOT YET released, although the release date looms close.

The blog of the main developer is here:
http://marksibly.blogspot.com/2010/05/hi-ok-heres-plan-i-am-currently-working.html

This language has been announced as free and open source (although the game module will be sold as a separate product).

The target platforms include Windows, Linux, MacOSX, android, iPhone, XNA, flash and HTML5

This may turn out to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @fuzzyTew - Just thought I'd let you know, monkey is now out http://www.monkeycoder.co.nz/

Answer (score 4):

I think [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) is what you're looking for.

- The some paying versions allow you to access, modification and extension of the Unity C++ code.
- It's web-mobile-desktop cross-platform.
- It allows using high level languages by default (.Net languages -but not .Net platform-, Javascript, etc)

Comment: Unity is a good source; thank you.
Ideally, I am trying to target Javascript, not code in Javascript.  I would like to be able to create something which can run in the browser without a plugin.  I would still need a good translator to do that with Unity sources.

Comment: I think your're asking for the impossible dude.

Answer (score 2):

[Haxe](http://haxe.org) has gotten much more powerful with the introduction of a complex macro language in version 2.07. I think this goal would be achievable with Haxe right now, and will only get moreso in future releases. The cons I mentioned still stand, but the language is open source and macros are powerful.